# Product and Sum, Variant 2b

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, meta-knowledge

My friends Peter and Sam are excellent mathematicians and always think strictly logical. Yesterday I told them: *"I have secretly chosen two integers $x$ and $y$ with $1\le x\le y\le 99$. I have told their sum $s=x+y$ to Sam and their product $p=xy$ to Peter."* Then the following conversation developed.

1. Peter said: I don't know the numbers.
2. Sam said:   I don't know the numbers.
3. Peter said: I don't know the numbers.
4. Sam said:   I don't know the numbers.
5. Peter said: I don't know the numbers.
6. Sam said:   I don't know the numbers.
7. Peter said: I don't know the numbers.
8. Sam said:   I don't know the numbers.
9. Peter said: I don't know the numbers.
10. Sam said:   I don't know the numbers.
11. Peter said: I don't know the numbers.
12. Sam said:   I don't know the numbers.
13. Peter said: I don't know the numbers.
14. Sam said:   I don't know the numbers.
15. Peter said: Aha. Then I do know the numbers now.
16. Sam said:  Aha. Then I also know the numbers now.

What are the values of $x$ and $y$?

---

Bonus question: How does the answer change, if we replace the lower bound in
 "$1\le x\le y\le 99$" by the new lower bound
"$66\le x\le y\le 99$"

---

Remark: This puzzle is a variation on [Product and Sum, Variant 2a](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8153/product-and-sum-variant-2a).

Comment: I would be curious to see a generalized version of this puzzle...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a Ruby program to cut out the tedious manual work:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

range = [*1..99]

pairs = range.product(range).select{|x, y| x <= y }
pairs.map! {|x, y| [x, y, x+y, x*y] }

def getuniqs arr
    arr.group_by{|x| x }
       .map{|k, v| v.length == 1 ? k : nil }
       .compact
end

def dunno pairs, n
    uniqs = getuniqs pairs.map{|p| p[n] }
    pairs.reject{|pair| uniqs.index pair[n] }
end

def aha pairs, n
    uniqs = getuniqs pairs.map{|p| p[n] }
    pairs.select{|pair| uniqs.index pair[n] }
end

7.times {
    pairs = dunno pairs, 3  # peter
    pairs = dunno pairs, 2  # sam
}
pairs = aha pairs, 3

puts pairs.map{|x, y, s, p| "#{x}, #{y}" }
```

Results:

```
llama@llama:...Code/ruby/puzzling8440$ ./pro_sum.rb 
77, 84
```

The numbers are $77$ and $84$.

For the bonus: The results are exactly the same.

This uses the same strategy as [the answer on Variant 2A](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/8156/39).

Answer (score 0):

Scala solution:

https://ideone.com/X48DIB

```
case class State(a: Int, b: Int, sum:Int, prod:Int)

val allPossibleStates:Seq[State] = for {
  i <- 1 to 99;
  j <- i to 99
} yield State(i,j,i+j,i*j)

(1 to 7).foldLeft(allPossibleStates)( (states, _) =>  
  states
   .groupBy(_.prod).filter(_._2.size > 1).flatMap(_._2)
   .groupBy(_.sum).filter(_._2.size > 1).flatMap(_._2)
   .toSeq
).groupBy(_.prod).filter(_._2.size == 1).flatMap(_._2)   
 .map(println)
```